# Stop loop iterations of functions with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

My problem is when I hover over something really fast, it executes the first function and then the second function when the mouse leave the text. The two functions are executed completely. I would like something like, if the mouse leave before a specific time, do something. For instance, change the text to "Fr"

```js
$( "#nav6" ).hover(
  function() {
    navsix(6);
  }, function() {
    <!-- clearTimeout(TO) -->
    nav6out(6);
  }
 );

function navsix(i) {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("nav6");
    var str = "Français";
    var len = str.length + 1 - i;

    var TO = setTimeout(function () {   
        elem.innerHTML = str.substring(0, len);            
        if (--i) navsix(i);
    }, 50)
  }
}

function nav6out(i) {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("nav6");
    var str = "Français";
    len = i + 1
    var TO = setTimeout(function () {   
        elem.innerHTML = str.substring(0, len);            
        if (--i) nav6out(i);
    }, 50)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topnav-right"><a id="nav6" href="#Francais">Fr</a></div>
```

Comment: Search for "debouncing".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I converted your code to a snippet so it can be seen right here on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with `clearTimeout()`. I added `clearTimeout()` right before each of your `setTimeout()` functions and declared `TO` at the top.

```js
var TO = "";
var hoverTimeout = "";
$("#nav6").hover(
  function() {
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      navsix(6);
    }, 200)
  },
  function() {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    nav6out(6);
  }
);

function navsix(i) {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("nav6");
    var str = "Français";
    var len = str.length + 1 - i;
    clearTimeout(TO);
    TO = setTimeout(function() {
      elem.innerHTML = str.substring(0, len);
      if (--i) navsix(i);
    }, 50)
  }
}

function nav6out(i) {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("nav6");
    var str = "Français";
    if (elem.innerHTML.length > 2) {
      len = i + 1;
      clearTimeout(TO);
      TO = setTimeout(function() {
        elem.innerHTML = str.substring(0, len);
        if (--i) nav6out(i);
      }, 50)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topnav-right"><a id="nav6" href="#Francais">Fr</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what I want to accomplish is that I want Fr to stay Fr when I hover rapidly over it. In your answer it bounces a bit less, but still bounce.

Comment: I see. Take a look now. I added a timeout to the initial start of the hover function.